# How to fetch result set of a query as dictionary using python, cx_oracle?

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I have the below code , and i want to return of my fetch_data_from_db as a dictionary, Currently it is returning a tuple. please let me know what code should be added to the existing to get the same ?

```
import cx_Oracle

class OracleDBConnection(object):

    def connect_oracle_db(self,connectionstring):    
        con=None
        try:
            con = cx_Oracle.connect(connectionstring)
            return con
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e.args)
            print str(e)
            return str(e)
    #print con.version

    def fetch_data_from_db(self,con, query):         
        curs = con.cursor()   
        curs.execute(query)          
        res=curs.fetchall() 
        return res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply prepare the column list and data list separately and build the dictionary based on those two different lists as follows:

```
def fetch_data_from_db(self, con, query):         
    curs = con.cursor()   
    curs.execute(query)  

    # list of table columns
    column_names = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), [
            d[0] for d in curs.description]))
    # list of data items
    rows = list(curs.fetchall())

    result = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in rows]
    return result
```